# Php curl_multi_info_read curl_getinfo. Warning: supplied argument is not a valid cURL handle resource

Tags: php, curl, warnings, handle, curl-multi

Part of my code:

```
do{
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    $done = curl_multi_info_read($mh);
    $info = curl_getinfo($done['handle']);
 while($running > 0);
```

This code results warning `Warning: curl_getinfo(): supplied argument is not a valid cURL handle resource` and i don't understand why. When i doing `var_dump($done['handle']);`     it's return `resource(7) of type (curl)`. Please, help me find the error.

Comment: I think you should just look at good examples at http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php .. your code has  major errors ...

Comment: Thanks!) You are right. First example solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the proper use of [`curl_multi_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php), please use the following PHP Example:

```
<?php
// create both cURL resources
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://lxr.php.net/");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.php.net/");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//create the multiple cURL handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

//add the two handles
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);

$active = null;
//execute the handles
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}

//close the handles
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
curl_multi_close($mh);

?>
```